# Crop array of images more efficiently python cv2

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, crop

I have some code that crops an ROI on a 3D array of images (so an array of image arrays) in python. I have code running now using a while loop, but it seems to be really slow. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this process as this seems to be taking quite some time for my large amount of imagery. Information and code below:

- dimensions of my images are 512x640
- I'm trying to crop out an ROI of 460x213
- `training_images` is the original array of images with shape `(n, 512, 640)`

code:

```
train_shape = training_images.shape

## Select ROI:
x1 = 175            # These values are the upper right of the image
x2 = x1 + 213       # Height
y1 = 4
y2 = y1 + 460       # Width

## Generate a blank array to input the values into
i = 0
training_imagesROI = np.empty(shape=(train_shape[0], x2-x1, y2-y1), dtype=float)
 while i < train_shape[0]:
   im = training_images[i]
   im = im[x1:x2, y1:y2]
   training_imagesROI[i] = im
   i+=1
```

Comment: same crop area for all images? just take a slice. that's pure numpy. also: Y means height, X means width. when indexing, Y comes first, then X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as

```py
training_imagesROI = training_images[:, x1:x2, y1:y2]
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: Ah man that’s way easy. I feel like a goof. Thanks very much!